# how to pass props into layout compoent in next.js

Tags: layout, next.js

I have a layout component that needs `onAppBarInputChange` prop. The `onAppBarInputChange` prop expected a function that take the input value from the layout component, and filter the todos based on that input value.

How do I pass the props from the todos page to the layout component?

todos.jsx

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import Layout from './layout'

const Todos = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')

  const todos = [
    {
      id: 0,
      text: 'make some projects'
    }, 
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'fix some bugs'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: 'cook food at home'
    }
  ]

  const searchedTodos = todos.filter(todo => todo.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()))

  return (
    <ul>
      {searchedTodos.map(todo => (
        <li key={todo.id}>{todo.text}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

Todos.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
  return (
    {/* how to set the query like this? */}
    <Layout onAppBarInputChage={() => setQuery(e.targe.value)}>
      {page}
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Todos;
```

layout.jsx

```
const Layout = ({children, onAppBarInputChange}) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <div>Todo page</div>
        <input onChange={onAppBarInputChange} />
      </header>

      <main>{children}</main>

      <footer>
        some footer here
      </footer>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

Note: I had read the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts) from the next.js website, about how to add layout in next.js, however they don't show any examples on how to pass the props to the `layout` component

Answer (score 0):

How about passing the input value through Context?
By adopting Context every component can observe the input value easily.

context/app.jsx

```js
const AppContext = createContext(null);

const AppContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const value = {
    query,
    setQuery,
  };
  return <AppContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>;
};

const useAppContext = () => useContext(AppContext);

export { AppContext, AppContextProvider, useAppContext };
```

pages/_app.jsx

```js
function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <AppContextProvider>
      {Component.getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}
    </AppContextProvider>
  );
}
```

component/layout.jsx

```js
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const { setQuery } = useAppContext();
  const onAppBarInputChange = (e) => setQuery(e.target.value);
  ...(snip)...
```

todos.jsx

```js
const Todos = () => {
  const { query } = useAppContext();
  ...(snip)...
};

Todos.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
  return <Layout>{page}</Layout>;
};
```

Comment: do passing a prop from the todos.jsx page to layout.tsx page does not possible?

Comment: You can do that using EventEmitter. I don't think it looks smart though..  
`<Layout onAppBarInputChange={(e) => emitter.emit("change", e.target.value))}>{page}</Layout>`